# how to filter efficiently for many terms

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, data-wrangling

First, I *do *have a solution to this, thanks to my colleague, Rosie Hartman, but I'd like to ask the question of the broader community to see if there are additional solutions and because I expect that others have struggled with the same or a similar problem. I was unable to find a solution here or elsewhere online.

Here's the problem: I'd like to be able to filter a variable based on multiple character values. I could do this with multiple filter() commands, but surely there's a more efficient way to do this. Here's some example data and a successful approach from RH:

```
library(tidyverse)
# example data
(dat <- tibble(sample = LETTERS[1:6], 
               sp = c("eel unknown","egg yolk jelly","English sole", "bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp.", "unid fish"),
               count = c(2, 16, 5, 1, 0, 1)))
```

For the sake of the example, I want to exclude "bass unknown" and "Heptacarpus spp."
`exclude <- c("bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp.")`

The easy solution where there are just a couple terms (as in the example) is

`dat %>% filter(sp != "bass unknown" & sp != "Heptacarpus spp.")`

but I actually have many spp names that I need to exclude from the data set and multiple filters would not be efficient.

One (to me, thoroughly unintuitive) solution:
`dat %>% filter(!sp %in% exclude)`

That's great, but why doesn't something like this work?

```
filter(dat, sp != exclude)
# or
filter(dat, sp != c("bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp."))
# or
dat %>% filter(!if_any(c("bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp.")))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your unintuitive solution is the one I'd go for. It's worth thinking about why it's not intuitive to you as it might make R programming easier. It might seem like `!sp` is inverting the character column `sp`, which I agree makes little sense. In fact you're taking the inverse of `sp %in% c("bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp.")`. It's worth looking at the output of `dat$sp %in% c("bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp.")`, to see if that makes any more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%in%` with `!` - `==` is for elementwise comparison, if the length is greater than 1, use `%in%` to create logical vector and negate (`!`). `if_any` is used for looping over multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
filter(dat, !sp %in% c("bass unknown", "Heptacarpus spp."))
```

Comment: Careful here: `!sp %in% exclude` negates `sp`, not `sp %in% exclude`. Do `!(sp %in% exclude)` instead.

Comment: Aha, you are right... I wonder if this behavior changed at some point. I am certain I made this "error" in the past, because your solution is more intuitive and I have conditioned myself to always add the parentheses...

Comment: Thanks...definitely a noob at this, so I appreciate the details, the patience and the experience!